# Erratic/strange program behavior, entry point hit twice

Tags: c#, windows-10-iot-core

Windows 10 IoT running on a raspberry pi 3. Here is my code:

```
    using System;
    using Windows.ApplicationModel.Background;
    using Windows.Devices.Gpio;
    using System.IO;


namespace CatFeeders
{
public sealed class StartupTask : IBackgroundTask
{
    private BackgroundTaskDeferral deferral;
    GpioController gpio = GpioController.GetDefault();
    int[] pinNumbers = new int[] { 17, 27, 22 };

    public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
        WriteLog("Starting");
        foreach (int i in pinNumbers)
        {
            using (GpioPin p = gpio.OpenPin(i))
            {
                p.Write(GpioPinValue.Low);
                p.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.Output);
                WriteLog("Ran pin " + p.PinNumber.ToString());
                System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(2000).Wait();
            }
        }
        WriteLog("Finished");
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(2000).Wait();
        deferral.Complete();
    }
    private static string GetNow()
    {
        string datePatt = @"M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt";
        DateTime currtime = DateTime.Now;
        string now = currtime.ToString(datePatt);
        return now;
    }
    private void WriteLog(string message)
    {
        File.AppendAllText("C:\\logs\\feeder.log", GetNow()+" : "+message + Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```

}

Here is the log file produced:

```
1/27/2018 10:55:31 AM : Starting
1/27/2018 10:55:32 AM : Ran pin 17
1/27/2018 10:55:32 AM : Starting
1/27/2018 10:55:35 AM : Ran pin 27
1/27/2018 10:55:37 AM : Ran pin 22
1/27/2018 10:55:39 AM : Finished
```

How the heck is the "Starting" log line being hit a second time? And it doesn't do it every time I run the program either...

Any ideas?

Thanks!
Greg

Comment: Unrelated, but why are you using `Task.Delay().Wait()` instead of `Thread.Sleep()`?

Comment: Thread.Sleep() isn't available in UWP C# :(

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. This is a [background app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/develop-your-app/backgroundapplications)? You get this issue every time when you run the program?

Comment: Yes it's a background app, I start it manually via the web UI. It doesn't happen every time I run the program, it just doesn't run consistently.

Answer (score 0):

I think it was due to me running it soon after it stopped. I'll keep an eye on it I guess.

Thanks for the help!